# How to control a motor with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, motor, dc, pwm, controller

I have two of [these 12 V motors](http://www.enigmaindustries.com/Motors/Bosch_EV_Warrior.htm) and a 12V battery.
I want to know what is the best solution to control the motor with an Arduino Uno. Does the motor controller need to be 100 ampere proof?

I though of a 100 ampere transistor connected to the PWM pin of Arduino, and then, it will control the motor with PWM.

Is a voltage regulator better than PWM?

Comment: Heh--Good luck finding a 100A transistor that can be connected directly to an Arduino. They tend to be VERY expensive and usually cannot be controlled directly by an Arduino. You'll probably need an in-between transistor that the Arduino can drive, and use that transistor to switch the Base/Gate of the high-current transistor. IGBTs are often used for motor drive applications, you may want to look into those.

Comment: yeah I will try with mosfet, it may work better

Answer (score 1):

The motor in the link is of different kind. I am not sure about it whather it is used as a generator or motor. Please specify your application. It is preferable that you first check the basics. you have 12 V motor and 12V battery, however the current capacity of the battery is not specified (ampere hours.)

In the question you have asked about how to control a motor from Arduino. Assuming that the motor is a simple DC motor, you can simply control it by interfacing a external H-bridge driver (IC) to your Arduino UNO or you can simply use Arduino Leonardo-compatible with L298P motor controller which has the same driver on board.

PWM is easier to control in a digital environment, the efficiency of PWM is way better than voltage regulation.